# MethodInvoker in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

Is there any in-built delegate like `System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker` for `WPF` ?

I was porting some functionality from `WinForms` to `WPF`, for this I was not wising to import winforms reference, is there any corresponding delegate in `WPF` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) is used in WPF also. And you can use it in Dispatcher.Invoke or Control.Invoke methods. Also you can use [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate which has many overridings. They both will be efficient.

Comment: `MethodInvoker exists in WPF also`, what namespace ?

Comment: @Brij Well, maybe my answer is a bit not clear. I mean you can use it from System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker, and WPF objects can use and accept it. But if you don't want it to reference System.Windows.Forms,  you should use Action class

Comment: Action delegate seems more likely to be used. Thanks @voo

Comment: I am able to call Dispather.Invoke method, but not Control.Invoke method ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, WPF controls don't have Invoke methods normally. There's nothing in System.Windows.Controls.Control, for example. Windows Forms controls have an Invoke method, but then they don't have a dispatcher (taken from Jon Skeet posts)

Answer (score 11):

You can use just like this;

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
  {
    // Do your work
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you have button control btnLogin
you can use it like this:

In WPF:

```
btnLogin.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate
{
    // Running on the UI thread
    btnLogin.Content = "TEST";
}));
```

In Winform:

```
btnLogin.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    // Running on the UI thread
    btnLogin.Text = "TEST";
});
```

Cheers!